# A map $X \to S$ is proper if $S$ has only one point $s$ and $H^0(X_s, \mathcal O_{X_s}) = k(s)$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

This is a question I have regarding [this discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/a/86063/111897) of the GIT Rigidity Lemma.

Suppose $p: X \to S$ is a flat morphism of schemes, where $S$ consists of only one point (i.e. $S = \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ where $A$ is an artinian local ring). Also suppose  $H^0(X_s, \mathcal O_{X_s}) = k(s)$, where $X_s$ is the fiber of $p$ over $s$ and  $k(s) = A / \mathfrak m_s$ is the residue field of $S$ at $s$, and suppose that there is a section $\eta: S \to X$ of $p$.

In the linked discussion there is the claim that $p$ is a proper map. Why is that the case? Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: This is false. For example, take $X=\mathbb{P}^2-\{p\}$ for a point $p$ over $S$ the spectrum of a field.

Comment: @Mohan You are right, thank you for the example! Actually I forgot one condition, the existence of a section $\epsilon: S \to X$, but your counterexample still works.